# Apigee App Services - Securing sensitive data in /Users collection

Tags: api, security, apigee

I've got a collection of users stored in the default App Services `/Users` collection.

Out of the box, to create a user, you only need to collect the following data:

```
{
  "username" : "john.doe",
  "email" : "john.doe@gmail.com",
  "name" : "John Doe",
  "password" : "test1234"
}
```

Name and email aren't exceptionally sensitive (albeit still should be properly secured), but if I wanted to include address, date of birth, mother's maiden name, etc., this data would become significantly more sensitive.

Luckily `/users` data isn't available without authenticating, but it is if I request an `access_token` and log in.

Of course one could easily design a front-end that obscures sensitive bits, hiding it from view. But looking at the underlying endpoint, it wouldn't take much to capture out my `access_token` and make an authenticated GET request to `/{org}/{app}/users`, thus seeing all of *every* user's personal information.

**Is it possible, through [roles and permissions](http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/managing-access-defining-permission-rules) or ownership, to limit segments of an entity only to `self`?** (For example, the logged in user could access their entire user entity, but only limited segments of other user entities).

**If not, is there a different way to approach this predicament and secure sensitive information in user objects?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remus,

Unless you delete or modify the "Default" role, you cannot see one user's data with another user's token.  So nothing to worry about there.

Also, as a matter of good practice, you should make sure you are sending the oauth token in the header, rather than in the query string (e.g. don't do ?access_token=''.

Rod

Comment: Thanks Rod. In many cases though, users need to be query-able (for searching the directory and such). So there's no way to hide chunks of the user entity from unauthorized users?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you put App Services behind API Services (Apigee Gateway) then rewrite the payload.

Basically (although it's a few extra steps than I'm going to be able to put into a short response) you would do the following:

1) Create a proxy in API Services to your usergrid.com target (https://api.usergrid.com/{yourorg}/{your app})

2) Create a /users resource.

3) Either use a Javascript callout to rewrite the payload with only the elements you want to expose or use the ExtractVariables policy to pull the specific elements you want to expose and the AssignMessage policy to Set a new Payload with only the response you want to expose.

Comment: Yeah, that's been my workaround too. Feels like there should be an easier way to handle it? I guess separating the data into a separate collection would work too, then proxying them together.

Comment: Using a two collection approach would work.  One collection, /userPublic could contain public info and another, /userPrivate could contain sensitive info.  You can create a connection between the /userPublic entry and /userPrivate entry and then set permissions so that only that user has access to the /userPrivate entry.  This does have the drawback that the /userPublic connection is not necessarily unique (and you may not want it to be).

Comment: App Services is great for a private API.  You can spin up resources quickly and build some basic user permissions, but it isn't designed to be a _public_ api.  When you get into conditional data you're really talking something more programatic than the simplicity of App Services.

Hence... Api Services.